# Convert timestamp UTC to PST in Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

We have a requirement, where the date time data are stored in DB in UTC format. But the UI requirement is to show it in PST format.

So we need to manipulate the data while building the API data in Java Spring.

Data which is coming from DB is in this format: `"2020-11-16T11:13:46"` [This is UTC]

I've tried below solution, but getting error.

```
  private LocalDateTime convertUtcToPst(LocalDateTime timeStamp) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" );
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(timeStamp, formatter);
    ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles" );
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone(zoneId );

    return zdt;
  }
```

[image]

Can someone please help me with the solution.
If you look at the return statement, it also shows an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add UTC to the timestamp,
then *convert* it

```
ZonedDateTime zoned = timestamp.atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
ZonedDateTime converted = zoned.withZoneSameInstant(
                            ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"));
```

apply `toLocalDateTime()` to get a date-time without the zone information.

---

Note: formaters are used to convert from object (~binary) to string and vice-versa, that is, `format()` (similar `toString()`) is used to create a `String` representing that object; `parse()` is the reverse, tries to create an object from a given `String`.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use the formatter? You already have a LocalDateTime

```
 private LocalDateTime convertUtcToPst(LocalDateTime timeStamp) {
    ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles" );
    ZonedDateTime zdt = timeStamp.atZone(zoneId );

    return zdt;
  }
```

Comment: Hmm... removed the formatter and used your code. But the time conversion is not happening. Post conversion also it returns date in UTC format.